# Liipimaginebundle in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, liipimaginebundle

I have the Liipimaginebundle bundle installed in a Symfony 4 project and after trying a thousand combinations in the configuration file:

```
config/packages/liip_imagine.yaml
```

I have not been able to make the image display work. I have read many posts that talk about this problem but I have not found any solution.

My configuration file config/packages/liip_imagine.yaml is the following:

```
liip_imagine:
    driver: "gd"

    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root: "media/image"

    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: "%kernel.project_dir%/public"
                cache_prefix: "media/cache"
```

The url of the images that are created are for example:

```
<img src = "http://localhost:8000/media/cache/resolve/ sylius_shop_product_large_thumbnail/da/9f/c71396fad5c120077fa0eac444f6.gif ...>
```

but the public/media/cache directory is not created at all.

Anyone who works with Symfony 4 has this bundle worked?

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly trying to do with LiipImagineBundle?  As the doc explains:

> Generally, this bundle works by applying filter sets to images from inside a template.

So you should **upload your image** with an other bundle (VichUploaderBundle) or take it from your assets.
And don't import your image with absolute path in your twig, you could use :

```
<img src="{{ asset('/relative/path/to/image.jpg') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```